# Placeholder text with "Comfortaa" Google font being cut off

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

Placeholder text of fields in IE10 of the font family Comfortaa seem to be cut off on the right side.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fA89K/2/

It only happens on the **initial paint of the browser in IE10**. I tested it with a different font and it works fine. Comfortaa seems to be causing the issue...any suggestions on a fix (besides using a different font)?

I could always `focus` and `unfocus` the form fields on load...but that just seems really silly.

Edit: 
Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I just tested your fiddle on Win8 running IE10 and it looks just fine to me. What OS are you running?

Comment: I'm also running Windows 8. Hmm. Resolution is 1280 x 1024. I'll check my other screen too.

Comment: One of my other screens is 1680 x 1050. It also has the same issue. You might have to turn off cache / clean cache to get it to do it in fiddle. I was having issues with that when I first tried to replicate it there.

Comment: I cleaned the cache, but I'm still not able to reproduce it. Sorry I can't help!

Comment: A screenshot would help to see what is cut off and perhaps make some hypotheses of what might be the cause. You should also include relevant code for reproducing the issue in the question itself.

Comment: The relevant code is in the jsfiddle. It is simply a form field with the font-family Comfortaa from google fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I'm seeing the same issue on Win7 IE10. It shows if you focus on the field then un-focus which doesn't really help.

The solution is to set the letter-spacing to .01em then onload set it back to 0.

Works a treat.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try this yet. I'll revisit as soon as I can Thanks!